# Attempt to get html from visualforce page results in "BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 String"

Tags: visualforce, managed-package, html, urlhacking

I'm running into a problem on a specific customer's org when attempting to get the HTML from a custom object's standard 'new' page layout.

```
String objPrefix = My_Object__c.SObjectType.getDescribe().getKeyPrefix();
PageReference page = new PageReference('/' + objPrefix + '/e?nooverride=1');
Blob b = page.getContent();
String html = b.toString();
```

Using the above code results in`BLOB is not a valid UTF-8 string` when attempting to use the `toString()` method.

This code is running in a managed package and has worked successfully in many other orgs.

I know that `Blob.toString()` method is only supported for UTF-8 encoded strings, but shouldn't  all VisualForce pages be encoded as UTF-8?

Comment: What context is the Apex running in? Is it in a VF controller?

Comment: Yes, I'm using a custom VF controller.

Comment: Is their 'new' page layout a VF override? If so, have they tried with a standard page layout?

Comment: @csnullptr What server is this running on? I think AP and/or EMEA servers do not render pages in UTF-8.

Comment: @MikeChale We are doing urlhacking from withing a managed package (e.g. http://force201.wordpress.com/2012/01/22/hack-to-find-field-ids-allows-a-default-ui-new-page-to-be-pre-populated/). We have overridden the 'new' layout in our package to point to a different page that redirects to the standard new page with query params.

Comment: Double question marks for one: `/e??nooverride=1`

Comment: @sfdcfox The customer in question is running on na0 so North America.

Comment: What's the language, locale and (as stupid as it sounds) email encoding for the user that has the problems?If you'll use Firefox's "view page info" on the page you're requesting - which encoding do you see?

Comment: @eyescream I should have mentioned that I already checked this. The reported encoding for the page is utf-8.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For shits and giggles you can try demoting it to ASCII before it gets to the page:

```
b = EncodingUtil.urlEncode(b, 'ASCII');
b = EncodingUtil.urlDecode(b, 'ASCII');
```

Or something elsewhere in your code is trying to stuff binary data into a string. Can happen in a few cases when trying to output:

- `Document.Body`
- `Attachment.Body`
- `StaticResource.Body`
- etc

Where's the rest of your class? Nothing trying to dump `unescaped` `outputText` into a page with funny `contentType`? :-)

Worth noting **NA0** (ssl.salesforce.com) is a [special pod](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/implementation_considerations.htm#topic-title_international) that does ISO-8559-1 *only*. Worth raising a case to Salesforce if this is inconsistent with behaviour in other pods.

You can determine the character set for your organization by doing a global describe and inspecting the encoding value returned.

Comment: While the first part of your answer isn't relevant to my specific question it is a confirmed issue with NA0.

Comment: Wow, so Salesforce has code that doesn't run on a whole pod? Was there a workaround?

Comment: According to SFDC the workaround was to have the customer migrate to a non na0 pod. What we ended up doing was disabling this auto-fill feature when a generic exception is thrown by Blob.toString().

Comment: All Salesforce instances are planned to be migrated off of na0 by the end of Q2 2014.

Answer (score 0):

I believe this exception would occur only if the page was rendered as PDF. PDF files are binary formatted, and not compatible with UTF-8 strings. Any Visualforce page that renders in HTML or any normal plain text format (text/plain, text/csv, etc) should work with Blob.toString().

Comment: But the Apex is pulling the results of the 'new' record page layout; surely that's not rendering as a PDF?

Comment: As far as I know, all pages in salesforce.com are rendered in UTF-8, so it certainly shouldn't be possible. Either there's a glitch in Blob.toString() or a bug in salesforce.com that's allowing the page to render in some non-UTF-8 compatible manner. This might need the attention of someone at salesforce.com to confirm. What language is the organization running in? Is it on an AP or EMEA server? They might use a different character set.

Comment: No, it is definitely not rendering as a PDF.